# Excel - Cell left of the median cel

Tags: excel, median

I have an array in excel: C2:C20. I want to find the cell with the median and then find the value of a cell in column A corresponding to the row. Some of the cells in the array might not contain anything. How do I do that?

**EDIT:**

The table is about observations.
The A column is about the name of the observation.

Sorry for the Danish language. 

Hyppighed = frequency

Summeret hyppighed = summerized frequency

**Sample table:**

[image: Sample table]

**Result table when using the suggested functions**

[image: Result table when using the suggested functions]

Comment: What is the relationship between the array `C2:C20` and the value that you want from column A? Also, I think that a sample of the table and an expected output would be useful.

Comment: There are only 4 values in C2:C20 in your example - is that where you want the MEDIAN from? Given how median is calculated in excel there may not be a "cell with the median" , e.g. with your example `=MEDIAN(1,3,19,17)` = **10** - what should be the result for your example?

Answer (score 1):

This will return the first median value found in C2:C20 and return the corresponding cell in column A.

<strike>=INDEX(A2:A20,MATCH(MEDIAN(C2:C20),C2:C20,0),1)</strike>

If you know exactly what you are looking for you can replace MEDIAN(C2:C20) with whatever you are searching in the Array contained in column C. If it is a string you are searching use "" around your text.

EDIT:
The reason you are getting N/A with your data set is because there is no exact match to the Median. In order to resolve this you need to replace the 0 with a 1 if you want a value higher than or equal the median or -1 if you want a value lower than or equal to the median.

Try this and it will give you the next highest median value if there is no match.

<strike>=INDEX(A2:A20,MATCH(MEDIAN(C2:C20),C2:C20,1),1)</strike>

For the purposes of doing an index look up the above method using the median function is inferior,

barry houdini made a great suggestion below which will choose the median value available or the next lowest one regardless of sorting...

```
=INDEX(A2:A20,MATCH(SMALL(C2:C20,INT((COUNT(C2:C20)+1)/2)),C2:C20,0))
```

or alternatively if you wanted to choose the highest one if the median is not available rather than the lowest one you could do

```
=INDEX(A2:A20,MATCH(LARGE(C2:C20,INT((COUNT(C2:C20)+1)/2)),C2:C20,0))
```

Comment: MATCH with 3rd argument of 1 needs to have C2:C20 in ascending order so I don't think you can guarantee that will work

Comment: One solution is to maintain ascending order by selecting cell A1 shift+click on cell F20 then do CTRL+T to put the data in a table and then make sure Column C is in Ascending Order by clicking the little arrow and selecting ascending order at least when doing this median search.

Comment: Rather than use MEDIAN(C2:C20) you could use this formula - `=SMALL(C2:C20,INT((COUNT(C2:C20)+1)/2))` that will return the median if there are an odd number of values in C2:C20, or the lower of the "middle two" if the number of values is even - you can plug that in to the original INDEX/MATCH function, with 3rd argument of zero, because there will always be an exact match, i.e. `=INDEX(A2:A20,MATCH(SMALL(C2:C20,INT((COUNT(C2:C20)+1)/2)),C2:C20,0))` - no sorting required

Comment: It is amazing that they required ascending or descending for the 1,-1 options in the first place. It really makes the Median function inferior with the -1,1 options, why even bother when you can just use SMALL and LARGE function?

Comment: I have populated C2:C20 with all the odd numbers ranging from 1 to 37 and it return the right column, however it did not return the right row. The median it return was C11 but through calcutation I figured out it should be C15. How is that possible?

Comment: I've understood your ideas and I tried to enhance them so I tried to replace COUNT with SUM but it throws a #NUM!-error. The problem with COUNT is that it returns sum of the row numbers and not the sum of the numbers inside the cells.

Comment: Highace2 sorry it took so long for me to respond did not see the "see more comments" button. You can not replace count with sum as this equation is a special calculation to get the closest available median. Please post your new data as it is a little ambiguous what your problem is.

Comment: In the original post I have uploaded a picture of the table. The index shows the right cell is different than what it shows.

Comment: If you want to get the next largest median use the large version, if you want to get the next smallest median use the small version of the equation. Can you post a little example for me to test in Excel because the equation appears to be working for me.

Comment: [File](http://files.wyrdnetworks.com/statistik.xlsx)    Here is a sample version of the Excel worksheet.

Comment: Okay I am looking at the sheet. test10 is the median frequency. Which cell am I supposed to look at now? Which row did you want it to return?

Comment: If you look at the index of the median it should be the 180th element which would be in row 15 or test14. That is my problem.